# ng-click is not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<li>
     <a href="javascript:;">
     <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" ng-click="export()"></i> Export to Excel </a>
</li>
```

Here is the click function, but it is not working properly.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please post your JS code as well so we can identify properly where you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @abc : show your script for angularjs.

Comment: Please share your button click code with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
     <a href="javascript:;">
     <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" ng-click="export()"></i> Export to Excel </a>
</li>
```

I think your anchor tag is doing the trick.

> use `href="javascript:void(0)"` else don't use href
>
> If it is not working, then use div or span, instead of anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Put ng-click on whole li item:

```
<li ng-click="export()">
 <a href="javascript:;">
    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export to Excel
 </a>
```

You are not obviously not clicking on the  element.